# How to analyze several CAD files with python

Tags: python, pyvista, numpy-stl

I have several cad files that I want to analyze. I want to analyze several cad files (step file,stl file), like a plate with several holes inside of it.
I want to extract all the dimensions of these files (height,width of the plate and radius of the holes) in order to compare them.

I didn't find any kind of examples on stackoverflow, or at least I didn't undertand.

I tried numpy-stl but not that far.
I tried pyvista also.

Did someone has done something like that ?

Thank you very much

Which solution is the best bewteen numpy-stl or pyvista ?
Do you have an other solution ?

Comment: Can you provide an .cad example file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What have you tried yourself so far, please include code.
And what didn't you get from other sources? Be more specific please.

What I can come up, and [found online](https://docs.pyvista.org/#brief-examples) is the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyvista as pv

# load stl file
mesh = pv.read("plate_with_holes.stl")

# extract the bounding box
bounds = mesh.bounds

# calculate the height, width, and length
# fiddle around w the numbers
height = bounds[5] - bounds[4]
width = bounds[1] - bounds[0]
length = bounds[3] - bounds[2]

# print them
print("plate height: ", height)
print("plate width: ", width)
print("plate length: ", length)

# use `find_radius` to extract the radius of each hole
radius = []
for hole_center in hole_centers:
  radius.append(mesh.find_radius(hole_center))

print("hole radius: ", radius)
```

Again, you need to be more specific and at least provide examples.

Comment: Out of 4 lines of text you're chastising the asker in 3. If you think the question is unclear, or it needs an MCVE: close it. It's also asking "which is best" from two random packages -- opinionated. Vote to close instead of posting a half-assed answer that won't run. You have more than enough rep.